# getting a weird value using nodes in c++

Tags: c++, conditional-statements

I hope this question wasn't asked before. I tried searching for an answer but couldn't find any. I'm trying to learn pointers and linked lists in C++. this is my code so far

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct node{
 int value;
 node* next;
};
node createNode(int value){
  node temp;
  temp.value = value;
  temp. next = NULL;
  return temp;
}
void add( node*& head, int value){
  node temp = createNode(value);
  // the problem is in this if statement
  if (head->next == NULL){
  head->next = &temp;

  }
}
int main() {
node* head;
add(head,4);
cout<<head->next->value;
return 0;
}
```

if I try to grab the address of temp into the head, in my main function, the cout will print this value "1634545454" and If I move the code line "head->next = &temp;" outside of the if statement, it'll print the correct result which is 4. I don't understand why is that happening! what is that value? is the condition inside the if statement doing anything to the address, or the value of head->next?

Comment: `head->next = &temp;` You assign the address of a local variable. After leaving the function, this variable is destroyed and the pointer `next` becomes dangling. If you want to do it this way you have to create the `node` instance by `new`. Though, `make_unique` or `make_shared` might be the better choice.

Comment: Also `head` is uninitialized, and using it will lead to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

You're declaring `temp` as a `node` (note the lack of `*`), i.e. a local variable. So it's automatically being freed at the end of the function.

Roughly speaking, you need to decide how you want to manage your memory. If you're going to do it all yourself, you need to use `node*` everywhere and remember to free your data structures when they go out of scope. But the more modern, safer approach would be to use `unique_ptr<node>`, which correctly captures that your node *owns* its `next` pointer. In this way, the data will be freed automatically when the time comes, but not before.

Comment: I see, this makes sense now. I overlooked the fact that temp will be freed at the end of the function. thank you so much! but how come when I delete the if statement and leave the "head->next = &temp;" line in the code, it gives the result normally?

Answer (score 0):

as @Silvio Mayolo mentioned you have two choices of using self managing memory or smart pointers , but as your base code was written in the self managing way ive fixed some of the pointers in your code.
the node pointer named head was not memory allocated and the temp variable most be a pointer so that the lifecycle dosent exceeds ,and if your using c++11 and above using `nullptr` would be better.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct node{
 int value;
 node* next=nullptr;
};
node* createNode(int value){
  node* temp=new node;
  temp->value = value;
  temp->next = nullptr;
  return temp;
}
void add( node* head, int value){
  node* temp = createNode(value);
  
  if (head->next == nullptr){
  head->next = temp;

  }
}
int main() {
node* head=new node;
add(head,4);
cout<<head->next->value;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You also made quite a lot of other changes, without any attempt of explanation.

Comment: I've fixed the first problem and added some explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct node{
 int value;
 node* next=NULL;              //node* next;
};
node* createNode(int value){   //node createNode(int value){
  node* temp=new node;         //node temp;
  temp->value = value;
  temp->next = NULL;
  return temp;
}
void add( node* head, int value){    //void add( node*& head, int value){
  node* temp = createNode(value);     //node temp = createNode(value);
                                     
  if (head->next == NULL){
  head->next = temp;                 //head->next = &temp;

  }
}
int main() {
node* head=new node;                 //node* head;
add(head,4);
cout<<head->next->value;
return 0;
}
```